# instantiation exception not able to put scheduler time on a class of project

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Im placing a scheduler on a class which implements Job interface, and when i create object of the class in the code and run the application, it gives me error as follows..any help?

```
public class Chart extends ApplicationFrame implements Job{   

//Main class
String imagepath=IASGlobal.APPLICATION_PATH;
XYDataset dataset= null;
public Chart(final String title) {

    super(title);
    final XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
    final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
    try{
        final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo
        (new StandardEntityCollection());
        final File file1 = new File("/home/iasf/workspace/iasf/WebContent/images/chart89.png");
        ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 1200, 800, info);
    }catch(Exception e){}
    ******************
    then some code
    ******************
    JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        //somr code here

    }
    private XYDataset createDataset(){
        //some code here
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final Chart demo = new Chart("Time Series Demo 8");
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("im done with 10 mins..");

    }
}


[ERROR] 04 Oct 04:56:00.046 PM DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread [org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger]
An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'ChrtScheduleUp.ChartScheduleJob'

    org.quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class 'modules.images.Chart' [See nested exception: java.lang.InstantiationException: modules.images.Chart]
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory.newJob(SimpleJobFactory.java:57)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:132)
        at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:358)
    Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: modules.images.Chart
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory.newJob(SimpleJobFactory.java:55)
        ... 2 more
    [INFO] 04 Oct 04:56:00.050 PM DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread [org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore]
    All triggers of Job ChrtScheduleUp.ChartScheduleJob set to ERROR state.
```

So im getting this error and im not sure how to tackle this..any help??

Comment: look to [InstantiationException Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InstantiationException.html) it seems this exception happens when you try to use the newInstance method in class `Class`, but the specified class object cannot be instantiated. when you instantiate `Chart` Class

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you do not have a default constructor for your job class.
To schedule a job using TriggerBuilder you need your Job class to have a default constructor.

Comment: It was extremely helpful for me. In my case I just had to REMOVE constructor from custom job extending StatefulJob quartz class annoteted with @Stateful